# Creating Large mysql Server Tables Filled With Random Data

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert 1000 different rows dataset, using MySQL store procedure. I found the query in SQL here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5148/populate-large-tables-with-random-data-for-sql-server-performance-testing/
and I tried to rewrite it in MySql. 
It gives me error code:1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'. I don't understand what is causing this error?

The table structure is :

```
CREATE Table tblAuthors
(
   Id int,
   Author_name VARCHAR(50),
   country VARCHAR(256),
   PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)
```

The store procedure in MySQL:

```
DELIMITER $$  
CREATE PROCEDURE prepare_data()  
BEGIN  
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;  
    set i=1;  
    WHILE i < 1000 DO  
    insert Into tblAuthors values (i, concat('Author - ' ,i ),concat('Country - ',i ));
    SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;  
END$$  
DELIMITER ;
```

Solution:

```
CREATE Table tblAuthors
(
   Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   Author_name VARCHAR(50),
   country VARCHAR(256),
   PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)
```

Comment: Please share table structure too

Comment: You're inserting a record that exists. For some odd reason, you didn't make the primary key `auto_increment`, which would fix your problem. That's what happens when you copypaste random code meant for a different database..

Comment: Thanks, adding auto_increment solved the problem.